# Visual Studio 2022 (Community) upgrade lost all RegexGenerators from project after update

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I've been developing a little Winforms project in Visual Studio 2022 Community. It has taken to having me replace my static `Regex` calls with these `RegexGenerator` 'pre-compiled' Regex routines, and they all have worked perfectly well. Today I upgraded to the Sept 20 VS-2022 update and when I loaded my Project back in, all of the `RegexGenerator` references now generate the error:

***CS0246: "The type or namespace name 'RegexGeneratorAttribute` could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"***

and

***CS0246: "The type or namespace name 'RegexGenerator` could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"***

I can't find any files in the Project that contain the missing code, and I really don't want to have to go through the entire project and put all of the original Regex checks back manually. Does anyone know if there's a way to get VS2022 to fix this? Or is there something I can do to get it to re-create the file(s) that it must have made in the first place and subsequently lost?

Googling this error required putting `RegexGeneratorAttribute` in quotes, and generated zero hits, so I assume that this is something that's new (in the wild) with VS2022?

Apparently it's insufficiently obvious that this is .NET7.0 (not CORE).

This is the affected code (all of which was auto-generated by Visual Studio), every line has errors now:

```
    #region RegexGenerators
    [RegexGenerator( @"(^[a-z][\w]*:\\/\\/|:[\d]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant )]
    private static partial Regex ServerRegex();

    [RegexGenerator( @"[^0-9a-f]", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant )]
    private static partial Regex SessionIdRegex();

    [RegexGenerator( @"(\\/\\*|\\*\\/|Master Key|[0-9,]+ bits|[^a-zA-Z0-9+\\/=])", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant )]
    private static partial Regex PrivateKeyRegex();

    [RegexGenerator( @"^[0-9a-fA-F]{18}$" )]
    private static partial Regex ValidateRegex();

    [RegexGenerator( @"[0-9a-fA-F]+" )]
    private static partial Regex HexDecRegex();

    [RegexGenerator( @"[\\/\\\\]$", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Multiline )]
    private static partial Regex BuildGetRequestRegex();

    [RegexGenerator( @"[^0-9a-f]", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase )]
    private static partial Regex PingRegex();
    #endregion
```

Comment: No, in VS2022, if you use a ```Regex``` function that's static like so: ```if (Regex.IsMatch(@"[^0-9]", someVar, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) { }``` VS 2022 will generate an alert pointing out that this is a static use and could be optimized by using a pre-compiled ```RegexGenerator``` instead. You can tell it to implement the generator, and it replaces the call with a function and creates a line in the file like ```[RegexGenerator( @"[^0-9]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)] private static partial Regex FnName();``` and, somewhere, somehow defines the stuff behind the scenes to implement it.

Comment: VS2022 Community, .Net 7.0 (not Core!)

Comment: Yes, several times; I also closed/opened Visual Studio, and even shut-down and rebooted the computer.  No effect from any of the above...

Comment: Okay, so, despite getting no hits for "RegexGeneratorAttribute" from Google, I managed to click around and ended up finding this site which discusses what it is: https://www.meziantou.net/regex-source-generator.htm and from it found the Analyzer ```"System.Text.RegularExpressions.Generator.Regex.Generator"``` is showing an exclamation mark and reporting *"This Generator is not generating files."* though clicking on it (right or left) doesn't do anything. I have no idea how to (re)activate it or what's going on/wrong with it. It does appear that this is, apparently, a .NET-7.0-specific feature.

Comment: Inexplicably, manually changing ```RegexGenerator``` to ```GeneratedRegex``` in the VS-generated code, wholly solved the problem... ‍♀️‍♀️

Comment: No RegexGenerator dependency means you have to generate the dependency.

Comment: I've already fixed the problem (as the comment above yours, and the answer below this, both state): For *some* reason the **NAME** changed from ```RegexGenerator``` to ```GeneratedRegex```. Once I changed all the names to the new one, everything worked perfectly... ‍♀️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea *why* this is so, but the original version of the code that was created by Visual Studio (quoted in the question) used the term `RegexGenerator` in the markup. After upgrading though, the term is now `GeneratedRegex`.

Manually going through the project and replacing all of the old terms with the new one, completely resolved the problem. Strange happenings to be sure, but I'm posting this in case anyone else experiences it and it helps.

Comment: in .net 7 preview it was `RegexGenerator`, but the final version they changed to `GeneratedRegex`.

Comment: They renamed the attribute in this PR on Jul 28, 2022 (during the preview): https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/72434